# BusinessObjects semantic layer results in Unsupported Major.Minor Version 51.0

Tags: java, jdbc, business-objects

I'm using business objects to connect to a new database using JDBC. I receive the error:

> Database error: (CS) “Java Exception : java.lang.UnspportedClassVersionError: <Path/to/driver> : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0” . (IES 10901) (Error: INF)

From what I understand, this is telling me that there is an incompatibility with the Java version used to compile the Jar. I'm assuming from the error that the Jar was compiled in Java 7. However, I’m not quite sure how to go about fixing this. I can find information about this error for other applications, but not BusinessObjects. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Without the ability to recompile the library your only answer is to use a newer Java version.  You must be using 1.6 or below which has not been support for a while.  Are you stuck on an ancient version of the JDK for a reason?

Comment: @stdunbar: SAP BO 4.1 (which I assume the questioner is using) ships with its own copy of Java 6.  I wouldn't like to try getting it running on Java 7 or later.  Apparently SAP BO 4.2 ships with Java 8 instead, but the upgrade may not be an option.

Comment: @LukeWoodward I am using 4.1 SP05 Patch 12

Comment: @LakeMichigan: in that case your options are to upgrade SAP BO to 4.2 or obtain a version of the JDBC driver that works with Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is your SAP JVM or JDK version is too old to read class format **51.0**.

Try to upgrade Java version to fix this problem.